# SQL to return record counts in X intervals

Tags: mysql

I have a table like this:

```
id    | created_on
1      2013-09-03 20:05:09
2      2013-09-05 17:03:13
...
```

How do I write a query to return a result of record counts that was created from Date X to Date Y in 7-day intervals?

So the result would look like this:

```
count | created_on
4       2013-09-17 00:00:00
2       2013-09-24 00:00:00
1       2013-09-31 00:00:00
10      2013-10-07 00:00:00
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can go to the beginning of the week by subtracting the day of the week.  Here is one way to do that:

```
select date(created_on - interval dayofweek(created_on) day), count(*)
from t
group by date(created_on - interval dayofweek(created_on) day);
```

If this is not the day you want the week to start, then you can add an offset day.

Comment: What about the time portion?

Comment: @NickC . . . Fixed it to use the `date()` function.

Comment: +1 I usually include an interval units keyword, like `DAY` after the number, e.g..  `- INTERVAL 2 DAY`   I've just never seen this type of expression without the units, DAY, HOUR, MINUTE, etc.  Just add a range predicate on the `created_on` to limit the rows... `WHERE created_on >= '2013-07-01' AND created_on < '2013-09-01'`

Answer (score 1):

Group by the date field, floored to the week:

```
SELECT
  count(*),
  YEARWEEK(created_on) as week
FROM
  yourtable
GROUP BY week
```

This assumes that `created_on` is a type that can be interpreted as a date:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_yearweek

This will get you weekly groupings, but you may want to then convert that field (which will look like `YYYYWW`) back to something more readable.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
SELECT created_on, count( id ) AS count
FROM `test_table`
WHERE created_on
BETWEEN '2013-09-01'
AND '2013-10-10'
GROUP BY WEEK( created_on )
```